# Getting null with OOP Deck of Cards Java

Tags: java, oop

So I am building up to a card game but, but I am having some trouble building the deck of cards and OOP in general so I was wondering if I could get some help. This is what I have so far.

```java
public class Card {
    String[] rank = {"Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6",
            "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};
    String suit;
    int value;
    String color;

    public Card(String suit, int value) {
        this.suit = suit;
        this.value = value;
        if (suit.equals("Hearts") || suit.equals("Diamonds")) {
            color = "red";
        } else {
            color = "black";
        }
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public String getSuit() {
        return suit;

    }

    public String getName() {
        name = rank[(value - 1)];
        return name;

    }

    public String toString() {
        return name + " of " + suit;
    }
}
```

The class for my deck of cards (so far) is as follows:

```java
    public class Deck {
    String[] suits = {"Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades"};
    static String[] cards = new String[52];

    public Deck() {
        int index = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            // For each value of card with this suit.
            for (int j = 1; j <= 13; j++) {
                Card card = new Card(suits[i], j);
                cards[index] += card;
                index += 1;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void all() {
        for (int i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(cards[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

So my question was when I print out the cards, I get something like

```
nullnull of Hearts
nullnull of Hearts
nullnull of Hearts
nullnull of Hearts....
nullnull of Diamonds
nullnull of Diamonds
nullnull of Diamonds
nullnull of Diamonds
nullnull of Diamonds... etc.
```

Why am I getting these nulls? What am I doing wrong? Also, any other tips to improve my code would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the following line of code from the constructor of class `Deck`.

```java
cards[index] += card;
```

You need to remove the `+`.

An array of objects in java is always initialized such that every element is null. Hence you are appending a `card` to null.

If you would step through your code with a debugger, you would have discovered that. All good IDEs have a debugger. You should learn to use it.

Note that the code in your question does not compile but I figured out how to fix it since the problems are minor.

For the sake of completeness. Here is your code with my fixes. Compare it to your code.

Class `Card`

```java
public class Card {
    String[] rank = {"Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};
    String suit;
    int value;
    String color;

    public Card(String suit, int value) {
        this.suit = suit;
        this.value = value;
        if (suit.equals("Hearts") || suit.equals("Diamonds")) {
            color = "red";
        }
        else {
            color = "black";
        }
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public String getSuit() {
        return suit;
    }

    public String getName() {
        String name = rank[(value - 1)];
        return name;

    }

    public String toString() {
        return getName() + " of " + suit;
    }
}
```

Class `Deck`
(Note that I added a `main()` method just for testing purposes.)

```java
public class Deck {
    String[] suits = {"Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades"};
    Card[] cards = new Card[52];

    public Deck() {
        int index = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            // For each value of card with this suit.
            for (int j = 1; j <= 13; j++) {
                Card card = new Card(suits[i], j);
                cards[index] = card;
                index += 1;
            }
        }
    }

    public void all() {
        for(int i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(cards[i]);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Deck().all();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, thank you so much. This comment was really clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

Your example does not look complete, as I don't see `name` field in `Card` class defined. But what I see is that `name` is initialized in `getName` methods. I guess you don't initialize it.
Either use `getName` in `toString`:

```java
public String toString(){
    return getName() + " of " + suit;
}
```

or initialize `name` in the constructor: `name = rank[(value - 1)]`

Prefer initialization in the constructor, otherwise if you refer to `name` in some other place you can get the same issue.

Comment: Thanks for catching that. So when I initialized it in my constructor, this time I get  things like "nullAce of Diamonds, null2 of Diamonds.." Why are these cards still preceded by nulls? Am I doing my initializations wrong? Thank you so much for your help by the way.

Comment: Additionally, I guess you need to update: static String[] cards = new String[52];
Are you sure you need to store strings instead of Card objects?